# My samba share does not keep permissions when moving files onto it. What am I missing?

Tags: permissions, samba, cifs

I have a samba server running on a debian host so I can share an specific directory with an ubuntu client machine.
This directory on host has no files on it.

Samba config on host is as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
[share_name]
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/16
   path = /tank/mail
   create mask = 0775
   force create mode = 0775
   force directory mode = 2775
```

On ubuntu client I have created a new directory as follows:

```
sudo chown -R 5000:5000 /opt/vmail-data
sudo chmod 0775 /opt/vmail-data
```

Then created the persistent samba share:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
//host_ip/share_name /opt/vmail-data cifs credentials=.smbpaswd,_netdev,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,rw 0 0
```

after sudo mount /opt/vmail-data directory is mounted.

Then I create a test file and test dir on this directory:

```
root:/opt/vmail-data# mkdir testdir
root:/opt/vmail-data# ls -la
total 5
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Oct 16 18:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct 13 09:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Oct 16 18:23 testdir
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 16 18:23 testfile
```

Problem is that when I copy or rsync another client directory to this client samba share (same client machine) ownership and permissions get changed as follows:

source (original) directory at client:

```
# ls -la
total 52
drwx------ 10 5000 5000 4096 Oct 13 10:33 .
drwx------  3 5000 5000 4096 Oct 13 10:25 ..
drwx------  5 5000 5000 4096 Oct 13 09:45 .Archive
drwx------  2 5000 5000 4096 Oct 13 10:33 cur
-rw-------  1 5000 5000    0 Oct 13 09:32 dovecot-acl-list
-rw-------  1 5000 5000  608 Oct 13 10:25 dovecot-uidlist
-rw-------  1 5000 5000    8 Oct 13 09:45 dovecot-uidvalidity
-r--r--r--  1 5000 5000    0 Oct 13 09:32 dovecot-uidvalidity.63480569
drwx------  5 5000 5000 4096 Oct 13 09:45 .Drafts
drwx------  5 5000 5000 4096 Oct 13 09:45 .Junk
drwx------  2 5000 5000 4096 Oct 13 10:33 new
drwx------  5 5000 5000 4096 Oct 16 16:46 .Sent
-rw-------  1 5000 5000   36 Oct 13 09:45 subscriptions
drwx------  2 5000 5000 4096 Oct 13 10:25 tmp
drwx------  5 5000 5000 4096 Oct 13 10:04 .Trash
```

If I try any of above commands results are the same:

```
mv /path_to_source /opt/vmail-data
```

or

```
cp -a /path_to_source /opt/vmail-data
```

or

```
rsync -avr /path_to_source /opt/vmail-data
```

after any of these commands results are the same at destination path:

```
ls -la
total 11
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Oct 16 18:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Oct 13 10:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Oct 13 09:45 .Archive
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Oct 13 10:33 cur
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Oct 13 09:32 dovecot-acl-list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 608 Oct 13 10:25 dovecot-uidlist
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8 Oct 13 09:45 dovecot-uidvalidity
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   0 Oct 13 09:32 dovecot-uidvalidity.63480569
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Oct 13 09:45 .Drafts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Oct 13 09:45 .Junk
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Oct 13 10:33 new
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Oct 17 07:15 .Sent
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36 Oct 13 09:45 subscriptions
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Oct 13 10:25 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Oct 17 06:47 .Trash
```

As far as I know these commands were supposed to keep ownership and permissions from original source dir to destination but this is not what happens. Moved files are owned by root:root and not 5000:5000 and also permissions are not the same.

If I add "uid=5000,gid=5000,forceuid,forcegid" to fstab mount options files are created with 5000:5000 as owner but this is not my expected behavior. Today files on origin directory are owned by 5000:5000 but in the future this can change. Ownership should be preserved no matter what.

Bessides permissions are not kept sync not matter what.

What am I missing?

kind regards

Comment: Is there any reason for using Samba to share files between two Linux systems? NFS is much more natural way to go in Linux-only environment, while Samba is mostly to have interoperability with Windows.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the time to reply. This same directory will be shared with a win client afterwards.

Comment: PS: Tryied with NFS and same results.... permissions/ownership are not kept when coppying/mv/rsyncing files to a shared directory.